# Scala: XML Attribute parsing

Tags: xml, parsing, scala

I'm trying to parse a rss feed that looks like this for the attribute "date":

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <item>
        <y:c date="AA"></y:c>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I tried several different versions of this: (rssFeed contains the RSS data)

```
println(((rssFeed \\ "channel" \\ "item" \ "y:c" \"date").toString))
```

But nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: `rssFeed` ? Shouldn't it be `rss`?

Comment: rssFeed is a variable containging the RSS-data

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "y" in `<y:c` is a namespace prefix. It's not part of the name. Also, attributes are referred to with a '@'. Try this:

```
println(((rssFeed \\ "channel" \\ "item" \ "c" \ "@date").toString))
```

Answer (score 14):

Attributes are retrieved using the "@attrName" selector.  Thus, your selector should actually be something like the following:

```
println((rssFeed \\ "channel" \\ "item" \ "c" \ "@date").text)
```

Comment: Note the .text to get the date as a String rather than a Node

Comment: Indeed.  The `text` method is generally preferable to `toString` since it will gracefully handle the case where your selector grabbed a chunk of XML rather than a `Text` node.

Answer (score 3):

Also, think about the difference between **\** and **\\**.  **\\** looks for a descendent, not just a child, like this (note that it jumps from channel to c, without item):

```
scala> (rssFeed \\ "channel" \\ "c" \ "@date").text
res20: String = AA
```

Or this sort of thing if you just want all the < c > elements, and don't care about their parents:

```
scala> (rssFeed \\ "c" \ "@date").text            
res24: String = AA
```

And this specifies an exact path:

```
scala> (rssFeed \ "channel" \ "item" \ "c" \ "@date").text
res25: String = AA
```

Answer (score 3):

Think about using sequence comprehensions, too.  They're useful for dealing with XML, particularly if you need complicated conditions.

For the simple case:

```
for {
  c <- rssFeed \\ "@date"
} yield c
```

Gives you the date attribute from everything in rssFeed.

But if you want something more complex:

```
val rssFeed = <rss version="2.0">
                <channel>
                  <item>
                    <y:c date="AA"></y:c>
                    <y:c date="AB"></y:c>
                    <y:c date="AC"></y:c>
                  </item>
                </channel>
              </rss>

val sep = "\n----\n"

for {
  channel <- rssFeed \ "channel"
  item <- channel \ "item"
  y <- item \ "c"
  date <- y \ "@date" if (date text).equals("AA")
} yield {
  val s = List(channel, item, y, date).mkString(sep)
  println(s)
}
```

Gives you:

```
    <channel>
                        <item>
                          <y:c date="AA"></y:c>
                          <y:c date="AB"></y:c>
                          <y:c date="AC"></y:c>
                        </item>
                      </channel>
    ----
    <item>
                          <y:c date="AA"></y:c>
                          <y:c date="AB"></y:c>
                          <y:c date="AC"></y:c>
                        </item>
    ----
    <y:c date="AA"></y:c>
    ----
    AA
```