# Read XML with name and value element

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I have XML like this:

```
<a>
  <b name = "d"value = "1"/>
  <b name = "e"value = "2"/>
  <b name = "f"value = "3"/>
</a>
```

I want to fetch the value where name is e. How can i do that in scala using XML library of scala (import scala.xml.XML)

I am trying something like this:

```
map{line=>{
  val rec = line.toString.split("\\^")
  var duration = XML.loadString(rec(4))
  ((duration\\"a"\\"b"\@"name").toString())


}}
```

But getting blank as output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: XML Attribute parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851365/scala-xml-attribute-parsing)

Comment: tried that but not working

Comment: What do you mean when you say "not working"? Are you getting an error? if yes, please post the error. Are you getting incorrect output? Please post that as well

Comment: I was getting blank. But it was resolved now when I do this:
(duration\\"d"\"nv")(1) \"@value"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spark-xml` if you are using spark. Add the dependency to your project in Maven or Sbt

Now you can directly read xml as a dataframe and perform an operation

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val df = spark.sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "a")
      .option("valueTag", "bvalue")
    .load("/home/sk/IdeaProjects/TestProjectForDemo/src/main/scala/test.xml")


  df.withColumn("b", explode($"b")).where($"b._name" === "e")
    .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------+
|b         |
+----------+
|[e,2,null]|
+----------+
```

Hope this helps!